# What are the role of the typescript configuration files after generating a Vue project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js, and I am wondering what is the purpose of the typescript configuration files after generating a Vue project. I executed the `npm create vue@latest` command and selected the **"Add Typescript?"** and **"Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development?"** options. It generated the following folder structure.

```
frontend
 ┣ .vscode
 ┃ ┗ extensions.json
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┗ favicon.ico
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┣ base.css
 ┃ ┃ ┣ logo.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┗ main.css
 ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┣ icons
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ IconCommunity.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ IconDocumentation.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ IconEcosystem.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ IconSupport.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ IconTooling.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┣ HelloWorld.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┣ TheWelcome.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┗ WelcomeItem.vue
 ┃ ┣ router
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┃ ┣ views
 ┃ ┃ ┣ AboutView.vue
 ┃ ┃ ┗ HomeView.vue
 ┃ ┣ App.vue
 ┃ ┗ main.ts
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ env.d.ts // What is the goal of this file?
 ┣ index.html
 ┣ package.json
 ┣ README.md
 ┣ tsconfig.app.json // What is the goal of this file?
 ┣ tsconfig.json // What is the goal of this file?
 ┣ tsconfig.node.json // What is the goal of this file?
 ┗ vite.config.ts // What is the goal of this file?
```

I am pretty okay with the `src` folder. However, the root folder feels very crowded. I do prefer the strong type nature of typescript, but these configuration files generate a lot of question for a beginner.

What is the purpose of these typescript configurations? Can I delete them to reduce the number of files, hence the maintaining effort?

Comment: No, you cannot delete them, they are needed for the project to work. tsconfig.node.json is needed for vite.config.ts, and the latter is needed to configure Vite, etc. The amount of files is the least problem as TS will require you to write a lot of extra code and learn some things that aren't very well documented.

Comment: @Estus Flask Do you recommend going for vanillia javascript instead of typescript at the beginning?

Comment: Absolutely. TS just adds cognitive load at this point and leaves one with the necessity to do some homework to properly type framework-related things that aren't really described for the most part. Half times I ended up digging into TS typings of package libs to figure out the proper types, it's ok as long as you're comfortable with both a framework and TS but can be overwhelming otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you are asking about are critical to the app build, so cannot be deleted but could be simplified a bit. They relate to the local build server (Vite) and the Typescript compiler.

> env.d.ts // What is the goal of this file?

This file imports the `vite/client` namespace, so its TS types can be used globally. The syntax is a triple-slash reference as explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-

It is included via the `"include": ["env.d.ts", ...` in the `tsconfig.app.json` so it's just a file, nothing magic. (At first I thought it was an "env" file but it's just another TS script)

To be honest, I'm not sure where these are used - possibly during testing, or within the build system itself. Your app shouldn't need this namespace as it's just about local hosting. This blog mentions their usage: https://www.jsgarden.co/blog/create-a-vue-3-component-with-typescript

> tsconfig.json // What is the goal of this file?

`tsconfig.json` is the main configuration file for the Typescript compiler, detailed here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#handbook-content

You will see inside that there are `"references"` to the other Type script project files `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.node.json` and `vitest`. It seems the Vite "create project" script authors thought it was a good idea to break the `tsconfig` into various bits - [apparently](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8483#discussion-4123598) in line with [the Nx toolset](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro).

> tsconfig.app.json // What is the goal of this file?

The "app" project is for the Vue web application in the browser.

> tsconfig.node.json // What is the goal of this file?

I am guessing this would be for server-side compilation of Vue.

> vite.config.ts // What is the goal of this file?

This is the configuration for Vite, as documented here: https://vitejs.dev/config/

Vite is the replacement for Vue CLI, which runs Vue in your development environment. It has a local web server with hot-reloading and does all the compiling for you via Typescript, Babel, Nightwatch and/or whatever else you chose during the install. In theory you (as a developer) only need to start Vite and it will handle everything else (build wise).

You only need to configure Vite if you make major changes to your app framework. For example I only changed mine when I installed a front-end framework (Vuetify), as all the other things like JSX and Nightwatch were configured by the "create Vue" scripts.